# import a dump file to mysql JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysqlimport

I am Using Java With MySQL (JDBC), and I want to import a dump file to database. what would be the correct way to do this?
I have tried the following code:

```
// function "connectToDB" connects to the Database, and not the server.
// variable sourcePath refers to the dumpfile.
    Connection con = connectToDB(USERNAME, PASSWORD); 
    String q = "source " + sourcePath;
    System.out.println("Q is: " + q);
    try {
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate(q);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    closeConnection(con);
```

but i get a MySQLSyntaxErrorException :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'source C:...\Desktop\dumpfile.sql' at line 1

Comment: change executeUpdate to executeQuery and see if it works

Comment: no i just tested "executeQuery" and "execute" but both of them gave me the exact same error.

Comment: If you produced the mySQL dump file using the `mysqldump` program, the easiest way to load it is to use the `mysqlimport` program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank everyone for their help, reading Their Ideas, I finally imported the dumpfile.sql
So if anyone has the same problem, A sample code that worked for me is this:

```
Connection con = connectToDB(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
/* Note that con is a connection to database, and not the server.
if You have a connection to the server, the first command in the dumpfile should be the
USE db_name; */
String q = "";
File f = new File(sourcePath); // source path is the absolute path of dumpfile.
try {
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        String line = null;
        line = bf.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            q = q + line + "\n";
            line = bf.readLine();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
// Now we have the content of the dumpfile in 'q'.
// We must separate the queries, so they can be executed. And Java Simply does this:
String[] commands = q.split(";");

try {
    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
    for (String s : commands) {
        statement.execute(s);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
}
closeConnection(con);
```

**EDIT:** Adding the connectToDB function:

```
private Connection connectToDB(String username, String password) {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + DATABASE;
        Properties objProperties = new Properties();
        objProperties.put("user", username);
        objProperties.put("password", password);
        objProperties.put("useUnicode", "true");
        objProperties.put("characterEncoding", "utf-8");

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, objProperties);
        return con;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Connection to sql database failed.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Couble you give more info on the connectToDB method. How is it done?

Comment: There you go :)

Answer (score 4):

I actually used @Makan Tayebi own answer, but i felt some improvements can be made.
1st issue may occur if dump file size is to large, than this approach is not optimal.
2nd issue might occur if data in the tables contain special character ';' within '' for data, splitting the file read in string on ; will also split on this ; and exception will occur.
Now, here is my solution. Just edited his:

```
Connection con = connectToDB(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
/* Note that con is a connection to database, and not the server.
if You have a connection to the server, the first command in the dumpfile should be the
USE db_name; */
 //String q = "";
        try {
            File f = new File(path); // source path is the absolute path of dumpfile.

            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            String line = null,old="";
            line = bf.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                //q = q + line + "\n";
                if(line.endsWith(";")){
                    stmt.executeUpdate(old+line);
                    old="";
                }
                else
                    old=old+"\n"+line;
                line = bf.readLine();
            }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
   }
closeConnection(con);
```

this code assumes that sql dump is created using mysqldump, or any other program which breaks line after each statement ends.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Also, One should consider that a line might end with a comment, or a white space.

Comment: Thats the reason i have mentioned that i assumed the dump file is generated by mysqldump and i am using this method on dumps from both mysqldump and SQLYog and this is working perfectly right now, besides i have discovered some dumps are in single transaction, so your method and my method both will fail in that case, for that case, we should read whole file and execute it in a single query.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run each statement separately and remove the comments

- start with empty command string
- Read each line
- trim line
- Discard the ones that start with --
- add line to your command string
- if line ends with ; run command and repeat to step 1

Comment: Thank You. I implemented such a code and put it in the answers. It seemed pretty tricky at first but it's the perfect solution :)

Answer (score 1):

as it is listed in the error the SQL statsement, you are trying to execute below query

```
source C:...\Desktop\dumpfile.sql
```

above is not valid SQL statement therefore it gives you error on line 1.
You need to open file containing SQL and then use its body as

```
q
```

Comment: this might help http://www.coderanch.com/t/306966/JDBC/databases/Execute-sql-file-java

Comment: your idea actually helped a lot. thanks. I just added the complete answer. ( Just Note that Before using q, we should separate Queries, Otherwise we will face errors.)